# Unable to provide % wildcards in cursor.execute query

Tags: python, t-sql, python-2.7, pyodbc, django-pyodbc

I'm interfacing with SQL Server from Django using `django-pyodbc`. I'm trying to build a query with optional parameters around a stored procedure which I'll pass to `cursor.execute`.

I'm constructing the query manually so that I only provide SP variables if they are sent via POST, which essentially leads me to this point:

I end up with the following query and params tuple:

```
query = "EXEC spapi_patient_match @PCode = '?', @FName = '%?%', @LName = '%?%'"
params = (u'PC', u'FN', u'LN')
```

Passing these via execute to the cursor:

```
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

I get the error `not enough arguments for format string`. I'm wondering whether this is related to `%` usage in python strings, so I instead double-up on them with the following query:

```
query = "EXEC spapi_patient_match @PCode = '?', @FName = '%%?%%', @LName = '%%?%%'"
```

And end up with this error: `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

I've also looked into trying to move the wildcards into the Stored Procedure definiton but that did not work and I've now read on SO is also ill-advised.

EDIT: As suggested by *Martijn Pieters* below I have moved the wildcards into the values tuple, which I agree is probably the correct approach, however this hasn't solved the problem and still results in the error `not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `%` wildcards to the **values**, and don't quote the parameters. You'll also *have* to use the [`%s` or `%(name)s` parameter styles for Django raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw):

```
query = "EXEC spapi_patient_match @PCode = %s, @FName = %s, @LName = %s"
params = (u'PC', u'%FN%', u'%LN%')
```

The Django-ODBC plugin used translates the SQL parameter style to the appropriate `?` style for the `pyodbc` adapter.

Comment: I realised my boobery right after posting, so I gave it a go as you suggested, however this still gives `not all arguments converted during string formatting` :(

Comment: Hrm, and what is the traceback?

Comment: The traceback actually points to code within django_pyodbc: `sql = sql % tuple('?' * n_params)`, whilst `sql = 'EXEC spapi_patient_match @PCode = ?, @FName = ?, @LName = ?'` and `n_params = 3`

Comment: Ah! But Django insists you use `%s` for the parameter style. :-)

Comment: Sorry I totally did not read your answer fully, and only paid attention to the `params` changes. Thanks very much!

Comment: I think the problem is that I failed to differentiate between pyodbc and django-pyodbc and thought I should be striving for the pyodbc method as stated in the wiki https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor which encourages "?" usage.